# Create POST request with Int key value, status code returns 422 or 415

Tags: json, flutter, dart

At first, I was confused about sending an integer value to the key id. Then an error will appear `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`.

After a long time of fixing it, I finally managed to fix the previous error with a code like the following:

```
class UserData with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, dynamic> _map = {};
  bool _error = false;
  String _errorMessage = '';

  Map<String, dynamic> get map => _map;

  bool get error => _error;

  String get errorMessage => _errorMessage;

  Future<void> get fetchData async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> userBody = {
      'id': 1,
      'username': 'bunn1est',
    };
    String _body = jsonEncode(userBody);

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://*******'),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: _body,
    );

    if (response.statusCode <= 1000) {
      try {
        _map = jsonDecode(response.body);
        _error = false;
      } catch (e) {
        _error = true;
        _errorMessage = e.toString();
        _map = {};
      }
    } else {
      _error = true;
      _errorMessage = "Error: It would be your internet connection";
      _map = {};
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void initialValues() {
    _map = {};
    _error = false;
    _errorMessage = "";
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The above code works fine, but I get the `status code 422` instead. And then I get the error `status code 415` if I try to remove headers inside http.post

```
headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "content-type": "application/json",
},
```

Is there something wrong with my class model, or is the error happening because it's from the server-side?

If the error `status code 422` shows because of my code error, which part should I fix?

**EDIT**

I've tried it on postman, and it works fine. I still haven't figured out how to store the key value with the Integer data type

Comment: Do you get the same result when trying to make to request without Flutter, for example with Postman?

Comment: I tried in postman, it works fine. The problem comes because of Int value key which can't be read by api

Comment: You create `_body` as a string, according to `http` [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html), this will set content-type to `text/plain`, and this can't be overridden. Perhaps the problem is that your backend is not prepared to handle `text/plain` body.

Comment: Your other option is to set body as Map, in this case content type will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and maybe Postman uses the same, that's why it is working with Postman.

Comment: I have found the issue. I need to convert the map to Json using `JsonEncoder`, instead `jsonEncode`. Thanks for your time

Comment: Good to hear, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this code

```
final Map<String, dynamic> userBody = {
  'id': 1,
  'username': 'bunn1est',
};
String _body = jsonEncode(userBody);
```

with this

```
int id = 1;
final  _body = {
  'id': id.toString(),
  'username': 'bunn1est',
};
```

Comment: Not working. Your code above will convert it to string. I really need key value with Integer.

Comment: did you try it ?? and  what  was the response from the server??

Comment: yaa already try it. 422 status code. Btw I've tried it on postman, and it works fine.

Comment: what is the api web site ??